# Reinstall Eclipse ADT keeping the state of my workspace

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have had a problem with the ADT for Android and I need to remove it completely and reinstall again.

It isn't an installation exactly, I just downloaded the zip with this structure:

- Eclipse (folder)
- sdk (folder)
- SDK Manager.exe

...and nothing else.

I would like to know the best way to set up again Eclipse ADT in order to keep the state of my workspace (projects, libraries and dependencies). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under 'Help' / installationDetails button

you should be able to list the features of the Android ADT ( debug, traceview, ddms etc )

and select them for removal.

Removing them should not affect your workspace or your project folders.

make a backup of your workspace just in case.

Comment: I can't open eclipse, I was following a proccess of an stackoverflow user in order to repair an error. I uninstalled "Developer Tools" and then I couldn't open Eclipse, so I need other way. Thanks @Robert Rowntree

Comment: Well , if your workspace folder is at a seperate path from where eclipse is install, then do a new install to a diff location.  Then just delete the old 'eclipse' folder.